# React Native: Invoke Reload JS within JS

Tags: react-native

While developing react-native app, is it possible to initiate Reload javascript with some javascript function?

[image]

Comment: use "Enable Live Reload" option. If you want have quick check of code instantly.

Comment: I know that option, thanks. But that's not exactly what I need. Don't want reload after every code change.

Comment: well u cant, its run on nmp server, so scripts has to be reloaded as far i know.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1071#issuecomment-99900736